# Move to another view when the user clicks on the OK button of the UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uialertview

When I display the alert to the user, if he clicked on the OK button I need to move him to another screen, how can I do that:

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"TopStation"
                                                message :@"Your internet connection is down, you will be redirected to the previous screen"
                                                delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you'll need to do is implement the UIAlertView delegate in the method you are using.

So if you have the class

```
@interface MyClass: UIViewController {
```

You'll want to change it to use

```
@interface MyClass:UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
```

Then in the implementation file you just need to implement the method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

From there you can move on.

Comment: how to know the index of the OK button ? the apple documentation provide only prototypes

Comment: By default the cancel button will have an index of 0